# how to make a transparent drop down button from an SVG?

Tags: php, html, css, button, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to set up a nav button system where you either hover or click on the SVG ( which is but it as a separate php) then there will be button drop dop, but more like transparent button.
text with a clear background (no box or border). how do I do this?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow! To help you, we need to see your code _in the question_. Please gather the relevant code and post it here. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more information. Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

**[The Many Ways to Change an SVG Fill on Hover (and When to Use Them)](https://css-tricks.com/the-many-ways-to-change-an-svg-fill-on-hover-and-when-to-use-them/)**

**#CSS Filters**

CSS filters allow us to apply a whole bunch of cool, Photoshop-esque effects right in the browser. Filters are applied to the element after the browser renders layout and initial paint, which means they fall back gracefully. They apply to the whole element, including children. Think of a filter as a lens laid over the top of the element it's applied to.

You can change the opacity with the opacity filter `opacity(<number-percentage>);` .

and you can put this in a hover css tag

```
.navbar:hover {
  filter: opacity(<number-percentage>);
}
```

And here is how you make a dropdown navbar:

```
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

here is the css to the navbar:

```
/* Navbar container */
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: Arial;
}

/* Links inside the navbar */
.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* The dropdown container */
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Dropdown button */
.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px; 
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit; /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
  margin: 0; /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
}

/* Add a red background color to navbar links on hover */
.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

/* Dropdown content (hidden by default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

/* Add a grey background color to dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```